# How to change page location at run time

Tags: asp.net

I have portal where lot of master page and all related page in root.

When user register his self then it will create a folder and copy all related file into the folder.

root master page and page url

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Layoutmaster.master.cs" Inherits="Layoutmaster" %>

<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage/Layoutmaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="Home" Title="Home" %>
```

Folder url of master page and page

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Layoutmaster.master.cs" Inherits="Layoutmaster" %>

<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/SubDomain/1/MasterPage/Layoutmaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="Home" Title="Home" %>
```

I want to change the Master Page File '"~/MasterPage/Layoutmaster.master"' from 
MasterPageFile="~/SubDomain/1/MasterPage/Layoutmaster.master" Please help me to change the location I have no any idea.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We can select different master page for any page aspx.

This is code

```
 this.MasterPageFile = "Master Page path";
```

This will work

For more information [Solution](http://www.dotnetgeekz.com/)

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably need to parse the aspx file to do this.

Another possibility would be to create a virtual path provider which would redirect the requests to the master page depending on where the file is.

Comment: Thanks,
can you give me any example.
How to do it?